# qt - How to make a label as fixed

Tags: qt

I am trying to make a chess game. So I am placing the board,coins as labels in a widget. Now I want  to make the chess board as a non-movable label. Because if I clicks and moves the board, it's moving. How to constraint it.

Comment: Your question is a bit cryptic. So if I understand right, your coins are labels and the board itself is also a label, all of which are inside some kind of widget? Of what type is this parent widget?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to look into the [Qt Graphics View Framework](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html). 
A [QGraphicsScene](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#details) would be more appropriate for what you are trying to do.

Quote from the documentation:

> The `QGraphicsScene` class provides a
>   surface for managing a large number of
>   2D graphical items.
>
> The class serves as a container for
>   QGraphicsItems. It is used together
>   with QGraphicsView for visualizing
>   graphical items, such as lines,
>   rectangles, text, or even custom
>   items, on a 2D surface. QGraphicsScene
>   is part of The Graphics View
>   Framework.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the wrong tool.

IMHO: You have to paint the board manually,or use graphics scene for this.

Answer (score 0):

I also agree you should be using graphicsview or something else but to answer your question you could to this

```
label->setFixedSize(/*a qsize or to ints are passed see http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qwidget.html#setFixedSize*/);
```

I would do

```
label->setFixedSize (label->sizeHint()) this will make sure the size is fixed but it is the labels optimum size (all content is visible)
```

Comment: @ Olorin I am trying to fix the label,thereby it won't move even if I drag it.

Comment: @ Olorin
 Yes. Fixed size is to fix the size, not to constrain it's moving